# QTableview goes blank after period of time

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to QT and experiencing a strange problem. I have a program that uses a QSQLquery to populate a qtableview. After returning to the desktop (Windows 10) after waking from sleep or screensaver, the qtableview is blank.

Refreshing the query (I have a button for that) does not fix the qtableview, the SQL connection still appears active and no error messages (from the SQL server) are generated and everything else (drop downs, text boxes etc.) appear normal.

**EDIT**
Thanks to everyone for their help and comments!

I have spent some time trying to reproduce the error and the problem is not related to the screen saver / wake from sleep. The tableview will go blank after a length of time (20 - 30 min). I still can't understand why this would be? Am I using the pointers incorrectly?

Again, appreciate any help, code for the qtbaleview below, my connection string is in my mainwindow.h;

```
MainWindow conn;
if(!conn.connOpen())
    ui->label_sec_status->setText("<font color='red'>Failed to Open 
Database</font>");  
else
    ui->label_sec_status->setText("<font color='green'>Connected</font>");

QSqlQueryModel * modal=new QSqlQueryModel();
QSqlQueryModel * modal2=new QSqlQueryModel();
QSqlQueryModel * modal3=new QSqlQueryModel();

QSqlQuery* qry=new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);
QSqlQuery* qry2=new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb); 
QSqlQuery* qry3=new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);

qry->prepare("select top 100 * from [dbo].[LOG] order by DEAL_NO DESC");
qry2->prepare("select MNGR from [dbo].[Staff]");
qry3->prepare("select SalesP from [dbo].[Sales]");

qry->exec();
qry2->exec();
qry3->exec();

modal->setQuery(*qry);
modal2->setQuery(*qry2);
modal3->setQuery(*qry3);

ui->tableView->setModel(modal); // table view
ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
ui->tableView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
ui->tableView->setStyleSheet("alternate-background-color: #99ceff; background-color: #f2f2f2;");

ui->combo_BUSN_MNGR->setModel(modal2);  // combo box
ui->combo_SP_NAME->setModel(modal3); // combo box
delete qry; // release memory?
delete qry2;
delete qry3;
// conn.connClose(); // moved to destructor
qDebug() << (modal->rowCount());
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that this is a bug, report it.

Comment: I didn't have the problem when using QT 5.9.1 so rolled back from 5.11 and recompiled, but it still happens. When I use windeployqt does it download / update to newer .dlls or something?

Comment: Difficult to say much with that little information you provide... Have you tried debugging? Attach the debugger to the running process and check your internal data buffers. You might try calling `update` or `updateGeometry` on the widget or even deleting and re-creating it...

Comment: Is table view completely empty or it has correct number of rows and columns, but all cells are empty?

Comment: It has the correct column headers and layout but the cells are blank. When you attempt to refresh the query / tableview it just turns to an empty grey square.

Comment: Should I try and force ANGLE instead of dynamic / opengl?

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior by minifying-unminifying your appl.?

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I have been trying to replicate the error and have edited my original post, the error is not directly related to the screen saver, the table just blanks out after a period of time, then the program becomes unstable and the user is forced to quit. I have posted a small section of code, appreciate any more help.

Comment: I'd take an educated guess and say you must keep your database connection open as long as the query model is alive. From the docs of `QSqlQuery`: `the connection must remain open while the query exists; otherwise, the behavior of QSqlQuery is undefined.` In the code you pasted, `MainWindow conn;` will lose its scope and gets destroyed at the final `}` (which is missing a starting `{`, btw).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their help and comments. The problem was not code related, it was found to be an issue with the VM configuration that the SQL server was running on.